# How to filter the data based on a specific column of sharepoint list using postquery

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am facing problem while filtering the data based on EmpPayGroup=DDAP. Below is the code I am using:

```
  request: {
      SelectProperties: [
             "Title", "EmpFirstName", "EmpPayGroup", 
 "EmpWorkdayId", "EmpCompany", "EmpPreferredName", 
 "EmpLastName"
        ],
        SourceId: '7c5090b1-2239-4ef6-9e93-1fa5e29f5c64',

        QueryTemplate: '{searchterms} EmpFirstName:' + 
searchText + ' OR EmpWorkdayId:' + searchText + 'AND 
EmpPayGroup:equals("DDAP")' ,

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.
QueryTemplate: '{searchterms} EmpFirstName:' + 
searchText + ' OR EmpWorkdayId:' + searchText + 'OR
EmpPayGroup:"DDAP" ',